A question on inequality Am-Gm-Hm
Peter has made a non-increasing sequence of positive real numbers where the i-th term is a. In this sequence, Patrick has noticed that $a_1 a_2 a_3 \dots a_{10} = 1$
After that, peter,
$\sum_{i=1}^{10} \frac{a_i}{a_i + a_{i+1}} \leq 57$
where $a_{11} = a_1$
Hearing this patrick said, "Then the minimum value of a₁ is k". Now what is the sum of the nominator and denominator of k?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

non-increasing implies
$1 = a_1a_2a_3...a_10 <= (a_1)^{10}$
So, $a_1 >= 1.$
Taking $a_1 = a_2 = a_3 ... a_{10} = 1,$
$\sum \frac {a_i} {a_i + a_{i+1}} = 5 < 57$
So, $a_1 = 1$ is achievable. So, the answer is $1.$

This question doesn’t meet the standards for the site. Answering it encourages low-quality questions. Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.
